# How to connect mismatched height baseboards?

Tags: floor, trim, baseboard, gap

I had a wall put up where a closet used to be and want to put in baseboard at the bottom. I have found that the floor is actually uneven and tapers at the end. So if I push the baseboard in for the green wall to make level, there's a gap towards the corner. It also looks higher than the baseboard on the white wall because the floor is lower for that baseboard.

I'm not sure what the best approach for this would be. I've thought about placing the baseboard where it is in the picture and scribing it, from where the gap is but I'm not sure if that would solve the varying height issue? I also thought of putting a corner block but I also don't think that would solve it. I'm very new to home reno stuff so any help would be much appreciated!

[image: corner closeup]
[image: wide shot with more wall view]

Comment: can you put something in front of it to hide the transition?

Comment: Almost noting in a real house is square, level or plumb; So we mostly just connect the dots to provide the illusion. That requires making cuts that are at odd angles so things match up (and/or sufficient caulking neatly applied where painting...)

Comment: The baseboard on the white wall looks pretty chewed up.  Have you considered replacing all the baseboard on the two walls?  It's more expense but it will be much easier.

Comment: You can loosen and raise the baseboard on the right a bit and push down the baseboard on the left to get them to match. But it is never going to look right unless you cope the new baseboard.

Comment: @ratchetfreak that's the perfect lazy solution.  I'd go one step further and make a bespoke little shelf with that angle so it can't go anywhere else in the house.

Comment: @Criggie
My friends and I were talking about either covering it maybe with a corner block or building shelves haha but I wanted to see other ideas people had since it feels kinda silly to start an entire new project because I can't figure out this one LOL

Comment: It can be just a plant or a floor lamp in that corner. Anything to block the line of sight to that corner.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to remove the original base back to the nearest joint or corner and replace it with new. Lower the new piece in the picture half of the amount needed, and raise the new replacement needed the other half. That floor looks like it takes a serious upturn into the corner there making the problem much worse. If it can be made flat, would help tremendously.

Comment: It's quite likely that long pieces of trim will need to be scribbed so that the top remains level while the bottom moves up & down a bit to adjust to the unevenness in the floor.